# Disable simultaneous login from multiple different places on Flask-Login

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I have a Web service written in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). User A uses some username to log in to the service. I want it to be impossible for user B to log in using the same username, until user A's session is expired. In other words, I want to disable concurrent, simultaneous logins per user. How do I do that in [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: When User A logs in, keep that information on the server side (database, file etc) and then always check that info from server side before loggin in if the user has already logged in.

Comment: do you know any examples of where this is implemented? I get the idea but I want to make sure that I can do it correctly

Comment: Was anyone able to figure this out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do is store some sort of session token in your User model in the database.

```
class User(db.Model):
    ....
    session_token = db.Column(db.String(40), index=True)
```

When a user logs in, you generate the session token and save it in the database.

Update your `User.get_id` function to return the session token instead of the user ID.

```
def get_id(self):                                                           
    return str(self.session_token)
```

In your `user_loader` callback you look up the user based on the token:

```
@lm.user_loader                                                                 
def load_user(session_token):                                                                                                                        
    return User.query.filter_by(session_token=session_token).first()
```

With this setup, the token will be updated on each login, which will automatically invalidate the previous sessions.

[Documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#alternative-tokens)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there any way to allow concurrent login for maximum 2 devices?

Comment: I've tried to generate and store the session token right after calling `login_user()`, but `get_id()` gets called before session token have the chance to be set. I want to set session token after `login_user()` is returned, in that way I can guarantee that the login flow worked fine.

Comment: I've used [Flask signals](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) to capture when [user gets logged in](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.user_logged_in) to store the session token generated using [secrets.token_urlsafe()](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-new-way-to-generate-secure-tokens-in-python).

Comment: But the notification happens after `get_id()` gets called. 

The only way I've found to make this works, was manually generating and storing the session token in the database before calling `login_user()`, but in that way the application can behave inconsistently.